# Extension to delay loading of link in new background tab

Tags: chrome

I want to change the behavior "New Tabs" are opened in google chrome. What I want is whenever I open new tab in chrome the newly opened tab does not start loading itself until I switch to that tab.

Is there a extension for a functionality like this?

Comment: Just to make sure i'm getting it right. Whenever you open a new tab, you want it to go to that tab, and start loading right away?

Comment: That could be helpful, also if you anything that makes them not run while switching to them.

Comment: [Footab](http://lifehacker.com/footab-speeds-up-chromes-start-time-by-only-loading-on-510414028) (via lifehacker) does what you want, I think. It doesn't allow more than one page to load at once - so when you switch to the tab, just hit refresh (F5/Ctrl+R) and it loads.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau, He wants to open that link in a new tab, but **do not** load the link until he actually focuses onto that tab. This is to save resources because Chrome is a huge memory and disk hog.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: For the record, that would fit much better as an answer, not a comment. Just an fyi.

Comment: @SarahofGaia I would post an answer, however I haven't used it, so it doesn't feel right...

Comment: Ah. I see. Okay, then.